# How to I create a smaller OS partition size when reinstalling OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, osx-mountain-lion, boot-camp

I want to install Windows 8 with Bootcamp on my Macbook Air but my OS partition is the full drive size.  My understanding is that you cannot resize the OS partition with Disk Utility (and it appears that way when I try).  I figured I would reinstall OS X and create a smaller size for the OS partition from the get-go.  How do I do that?

Comment: Instead of re-installing, how about trying to use `/Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant` instead, which can resize and set up windows boot camp for you?

Comment: When I ran Bootcamp Assistant it told me I didn't have enough free space to continue. I was going to free space but then I got the bright idea to reinstall. I hadn't even considered that once I had freed space that it would do a shrink for me. I will try it. In any case can a smaller OS partition size be specified at OS install time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had no trouble resizing my main OS partition with Disk Utility.  If you open Disk Utility, and select the physical drive (probably the top-most item on the left), Disk Utility will give you a "Partition" option, after "First Aid" and "Erase", before 'RAID' and 'Restore'.

For additional instructions, please refer to Disk Utility's Help.  On the first page, there is an article "Partition a Disk": selecting it will give another article, in which you wish to select "Partition a Disk" again.  This will tell you how to shrink your OSX partition so you have room for Boot Camp...   I suggest reading this first as well as other related topics, and then, as the article (and comments) suggest, open Boot Camp Assistant, for the rest.

If you still don't have enough space, then you might consider getting an external disk.

Comment: All the controls on the screen are locked read-only.  No drag handle on the partition box and no way to edit the value in the text box.  This http://snag.gy/95qpY.jpg screenshot shows this with my now dual-partition system, but it was the same when I just had a single partition.

Comment: Click in the "Untitled" section;  This should allow you to delete the partition, assuming there's nothing on it, as the image you provided seems to suggest.  (a great help, btw)   However, it seems to also suggest that "Matt's Disk" is also empty.  (I see you might have started a reinstall, which would explain it.)

Comment: IIRC, when booting in 'Recovery' mode, which would be required to re-install, you would have the option of running "Disk Utility" beforehand, where you ought to be able to re-partition and erase the hard drive in any number of ways, and select the volume to install mtn lion on.  If you do do another screen capture, could you provide the whole "Disk Utility" window?  It has other useful information down below your crop.